# Is $\sqrt[3]{7+5 \sqrt{2}}+\sqrt[3]{20-14 \sqrt{2}}$ a rational number?

Tags: rational-numbers, nested-radicals, rationality-testing

Is there a way to show that

$$\alpha=\sqrt[3]{7+5 \sqrt{2}}+\sqrt[3]{20-14 \sqrt{2}}$$

is a rational number?

I found $\alpha=3$ from doing simplifications. But, I would like to known a different approach.

Comment: What do you mean by "I know $\alpha=3$ doing simplifications"?  How you get $3$?

Comment: Well you've already said that you know the answer is $3$ from simplifications - $\sqrt[3]{7+5 \sqrt{2}}+\sqrt[3]{20-14 \sqrt{2}}=\sqrt[3]{(\sqrt{2}+1)^3}+\sqrt[3]{(2-\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{2}+1+2-\sqrt{2}=3$. What other type of argument are you looking for?

Comment: I see by a calculator it is (to calculator accuracy) $3$ as you say. But it would improve your question if you include the steps to show it is $3$ exactly without using a calculator.

Comment: @JC12 $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{7+5 \sqrt{2}}+\sqrt[3]{20-14 \sqrt{2}}=\sqrt[3]{1+3\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt[3]{8-12\sqrt{2}+12-2\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt[3]{(1+\sqrt{2})^3}+\sqrt[3]{(2-\sqrt{2})^3}=3$

Comment: Cube both sides of the equation. Write $\alpha=a+\sqrt{b}$ and see if $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$. If not, then you are sure. If so, we just need to see if $\sqrt{b}\in\mathbb{Q}$ which is easy to check.

Comment: @KevinDuran, I think you meant $\sqrt[3]{1+3\sqrt2+6+2\sqrt2}$ instead of $\sqrt[3]{1+3\sqrt2+2\sqrt2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Anay's idea of cubing both sides looks promising, but there is a little subtlety in the method.  Let's explore.

Start with

$\alpha=\sqrt[3]{7+5\sqrt2}+\sqrt[3]{20-14\sqrt2}$

Cube with the Binomial Theorem:

$\alpha^3=\color{blue}{7+5\sqrt2}+\color{brown}{3(\sqrt[3]{7+5\sqrt2})^2\sqrt[3]{20-14\sqrt2}+3\sqrt[3]{7+5\sqrt2}(\sqrt[3]{20-14\sqrt2})^2}+\color{blue}{20-14\sqrt2}$

Combine the terms that are the same color in the above expression:

$\alpha^3=\color{blue}{27-9\sqrt2}+\color{brown}{3\sqrt[3]{7+5\sqrt2}\sqrt[3]{20-14\sqrt2}(\sqrt[3]{7+5\sqrt2}+\sqrt[3]{20-14\sqrt2})}$

$\alpha^3=27-9\sqrt2+3\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt2}\alpha$

Render $\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt2}=\sqrt2$:

$\alpha^3-3\sqrt2\alpha-27+9\sqrt2=0$

Now suppose that $\alpha$ is rational in this final equation.  Then the left side is rational only if $\sqrt2$ has a zero overall coefficient, meaning $3\alpha-9=0$ or $\alpha=3$ is the only possible rational root.  So, we try this value and find that the equation holds.  Thus $\alpha=3$ checks out.

We have the possibility that even though $\alpha=3$ is a root of the cubic equation, it may not be the original sum of the cube roots with which we started.  To check that, divide the cubic by $\alpha-3$ to get a quadratic equation whose remaining real roots are other possibilities for $\alpha$.   This gives the factorization

$(\alpha-3)(\alpha^2+3\alpha+9-3\sqrt2)=0$

The discriminant of the quadratic factor is $-27+12\sqrt2=-\sqrt{729}+\sqrt{288}<0$.  Thereby $\alpha=3$ is the only real root and must be the actual sum $\sqrt[3]{7+5\sqrt2}+\sqrt[3]{20-14\sqrt2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Note $\sqrt[3]{20-14 \sqrt{2}}=\sqrt2 \cdot \sqrt[3]{5 \sqrt{2}-7}$ and assume $\sqrt[3]{5\sqrt{2}\pm7}=p\sqrt2\pm q$. Then

$$\alpha
=(p\sqrt2+q)+\sqrt2(p\sqrt2-q)=(q+2p)+(p-q)\sqrt2
$$

For $a$ to be rational requires $p=q=\frac{\sqrt[3]{5 \sqrt{2}+7}}{\sqrt2+1}
= \sqrt[3]{\frac{ 5 \sqrt{2}+7}{(\sqrt2+1)^3 }}=1$ to be rational, which is indeed.